# Kendo UI Dropdownlist not display correct value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown, kendo-datasource

I had a situation like this, my dropdownlist supposedly it should display GUEST HOUSE based on my `userPropertyID=3` but somehow it still not display the right value in dropdownlist. Need your help, thank you for your time.

```js
  var userPropertyID = 3;

  var propertyTBL = [
  {"propertyID":"1","propertyName":"HOTEL"},
  {"propertyID":"2","propertyName":"RESORT"},
  {"propertyID":"3","propertyName":"GUEST HOUSE"},
  {"propertyID":"4","propertyName":"HOME"},
  {"propertyID":"5","propertyName":"MOTEL"}];

  
  var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "propertyName",
    dataValueField: "propertyID",
    dataSource: propertyTBL
  });
  dropdownlist.select(userPropertyID);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.silver.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <style>*{font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;}</style>
<body>
Property Name:<input id="dropdownlist"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you didn't assign correct kendo widget into variable. So it doesn't know kendo's functions.

Correct way would be this (by using .data('kendoDropDownList'))

```
var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data('kendoDropDownList');
```

so in your case, you need change your part of code to this.

```
var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "propertyName",
    dataValueField: "propertyID",
    dataSource: propertyTBL
}).data('kendoDropDownList');
```

But remember that indexing starts at 0 (I see in your code, that at index 3, you have again value HOME as is at index 0, so don't get confused by that).

Now calling *.value()* function will work

```
dropdownlist.select(userPropertyID - 1);
```

Eventually, if you set value immediately after you create widget even in your real application, you can use [value](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/value) property to set it up

```
var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "propertyName",
    dataValueField: "propertyID",
    dataSource: propertyTBL,
    value: userPropertyID
}).data('kendoDropDownList');
```

EDIT: To make it complete, here is your modified code snippet

```js
  var userPropertyID = 3;

  var propertyTBL = [
  {"propertyID":"1","propertyName":"HOTEL"},
  {"propertyID":"2","propertyName":"RESORT"},
  {"propertyID":"3","propertyName":"GUEST HOUSE"},
  {"propertyID":"4","propertyName":"HOME"},
  {"propertyID":"5","propertyName":"MOTEL"}];

  
  var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "propertyName",
    dataValueField: "propertyID",
    dataSource: propertyTBL
  }).data('kendoDropDownList');
  dropdownlist.select(userPropertyID - 1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.silver.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <style>*{font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;}</style>
<body>
Property Name:<input id="dropdownlist"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, obliviously I need to read the documentation more.